# transforming xml elements with attributes into all attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

So, I have some XML data that I downloaded from the government that has this basic structure:

```xml
<axis pos="6" values="3">
  <title>Device</title>
  <label code="7">Autologous Tissue Substitute</label>
  <label code="J">Synthetic Substitute</label>
  <label code="K">Nonautologous Tissue Substitute</label>
</axis>
```

And I would like to use XSLT to get output that looks like this (which I will then load into a relational database table):

```xml
<axis pos="6" title="Device" code="7" label="Autologous Tissue Substitute" />
<axis pos="6" title="Device" code="J" label="Synthetic Substitute" />
<axis pos="6" title="Device" code="K" label="Nonautologous Tissue Substitute" />
```

I don't really know XSLT very well (ie. i just read a few tutorials on the web for about an hour), so what I came up with is:

```xml
<xsl:template match="axis">
    <axis pos="{pos}">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </axis>
</xsl:template>
```

This results in:

```xml
<axis pos="" title="Device" label="Nonautologous Tissue Substitute"/>
```

The first problem is the empty value for the pos attribute and the missing code attribute.  But the bigger issue is that I only get one axis tag instead of three.  I have the feeling that I'm either working on the wrong tag level or I'm missing a for-each.

Any help / links to useful tutorials is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you want one `axis` node output for each child `label` node, it's the latter you need to iterate over. From there you can reference back up to the parent for the info that lives at that level.

Also, meet `apply-templates`, which is generally preferred in XSLT over `for-each`.

```
<!-- kick things off -->
<xsl:template match="axis">
    <xsl:apply-templates select='label' />
</xsl:template>

<!-- do axis node, one per label child in source XML -->
<xsl:template match='label'>
    <axis pos='{../@pos}' title='{../title}' code='{@code}' label='{.}' />
</xsl:template>
```

Note your `pos` attribute was empty because attributes are referenced via the prefix `@`; to omit it tells the XSLT processor to look for a child node, not an attribute.

Runnable demo at [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/usb0XS) (see output **source**)

Comment: this is nice.  is there a way to do it without having to specify the attributes of axis and label, but have it done dynamically (in case the format changes)?